# Istio Traffic from istio-enabled namespace to another namespace

Tags: networking, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I've been trying a lot to make this scenario work. I have to namespaces:

- namespace: mongodb  (Istio disabled, it's actually a mongodb operator with a cluster here)
- namespace: app (Istio enabled)

From a third namespace, say default, I can reach the mongodb endpoint with the fqnd: `mongodb-standalone-0.mongodb-standalone-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local`

But from the app namespace that has istio enabled, I've tried the following without success:

External name service

```
kind: "Service"
apiVersion: "v1"
metadata:
  namespace: app
  labels:
    app: mongodb
    service: mongodb
  name: mongodb
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: mongodb-standalone-0.mongodb-standalone-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local
  ports:
  - port: 27017
status:
 loadBalancer: {}
```

- ping works, but traffic to the port 27017 doesn't

Virtual service + service

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: mongodb
spec:
  hosts:
  - mongodb
  tcp:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: mongodb-standalone-0.mongodb-standalone-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v1
--- 
kind: "Service"
apiVersion: "v1"
metadata:
  namespace: app
  labels:
    app: mongodb
    service: mongodb
  name: mongodb
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "tcp-mongodb"
    port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
status:
 loadBalancer: {}
```

Service Entry:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: mongodb
spec:
  hosts:
  - mongodb-standalone-0.mongodb-standalone-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local
  #- mongodb
  ports:
  - number: 27017
    name: tcp-mongodb
    protocol: TCP
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  resolution: DNS
  endpoints:
  - address: mongodb-standalone-0.mongodb-standalone-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local
```

but nothing seems to help to reach the mongodb namespace from the Istio enabled namespace. Any ideas?

Comment: I would recommend to try to do that without externalName, there is related [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2018/egress-mongo/#control-tcp-egress-traffic-without-a-gateway) about service entry, where you can find an example for mongodb. Additionally take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58958939/istio-serviceentry-for-multiple-external-databases-going-to-the-same-database) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62467311/11977760).

Answer (score 0):

Injecting Databases with istio is complicated. In istio You can set up Database without injecting and then add it to Istio registry using ServiceEntry object so it would be able to communicate with the rest of istio services. **As I mentioned in comments I would recommend to try to do that without externalName as there is no specific documentation for that.**

To add your mongodb database to istio you can use [ServiceEntry](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/service-entry/).

> ServiceEntry enables adding additional entries into Istio’s internal service registry, so that auto-discovered services in the mesh can access/route to these manually specified services. A service entry describes the properties of a service (DNS name, VIPs, ports, protocols, endpoints). These services could be external to the mesh (e.g., web APIs) or mesh-internal services that are not part of the platform’s service registry (e.g., a set of VMs talking to services in Kubernetes). In addition, the endpoints of a service entry can also be dynamically selected by using the workloadSelector field. These endpoints can be VM workloads declared using the WorkloadEntry object or Kubernetes pods. The ability to select both pods and VMs under a single service allows for migration of services from VMs to Kubernetes without having to change the existing DNS names associated with the services.

Example of ServiceEntry

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: external-svc-mongocluster
spec:
  hosts:
  - mymongodb.somedomain # not used
  addresses:
  - 192.192.192.192/24 # VIPs
  ports:
  - number: 27018
    name: mongodb
    protocol: MONGO
  location: MESH_INTERNAL
  resolution: STATIC
  endpoints:
  - address: 2.2.2.2
  - address: 3.3.3.3
```

If You have mtls enabled(enabled by default since istio 1.5 version) You will also need DestinationRule that will define how to communicate with the external service.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: mtls-mongocluster
spec:
  host: mymongodb.somedomain
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: MUTUAL
      clientCertificate: /etc/certs/myclientcert.pem
      privateKey: /etc/certs/client_private_key.pem
      caCertificates: /etc/certs/rootcacerts.pem
```

---

Additionally take a look at this links

- https://istiobyexample.dev/databases/
- https://istio.io/latest/blog/2018/egress-mongo/
- [Istio ServiceEntry for multiple external databases going to the same database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58958939/istio-serviceentry-for-multiple-external-databases-going-to-the-same-database)